# Finding 2 numbers and send a message about it

Tags: python-2.7

I need to find 2 random numbers from 1-100 and send a message:
to high or to low according to the random number,
This is the code I wrote..., it doesn't work after the first if...,

```
from random import randint
a = int(randint(1, 101))
guess = int(raw_input("guess the number:"))

while guess != a:
    if guess > a:
        print "bigger"
        print guess
        print a
    elif guess < a:
        print "smaller"
        print guess
        print a
    else:
        print "correct"
        print guess
        print a
        break
    guess = raw_input("guess a new number:")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
a = randint(1, 101)
guess = input("guess the number:")

while True:
    if guess > a:
        print "your guess is too high"
    elif guess < a:
        print "your guess is too low"
    else:
        print 'You are correct'
        break
    guess = input("guess again:")
```

If I understood correctly your aim this code will work. It will stop when he guesses correctly the number. You had many mistakes with input and int. For future reference - if you use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` it will automatically pick the right type for the var.

In order to make your code work as intended just fix the input:

```
from random import randint
a = int(randint(1, 101))
guess = int(raw_input("guess the number:"))

while True:
    if guess > a:
        print "bigger"
        print guess
        print a
    elif guess < a:
        print "smaller"
        print guess
        print a
    else:
        print "correct"
        print guess
        print a
        break
    guess = input("guess a new number:") #not raw_input()
```

Comment: Thanks, the code you write works fine, but there's still a problem with the "else", let say the random number is 16, so when I type 16 it'll end the session, i want the word "correct" will be print...

Comment: Removed the `guess != a` and stayed with the `break` alone

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful